# Base domain mapping broken for certain domains

Tags: google-cloud-run

I am trying to map a base domain name to a Google Cloud Run (fully managed) service. The following mappings work successfully:

- Any Cloud Run service -> something.aaa.com (Immediately gives CNAME Records)
- Any Cloud Run service -> bbb.com (Immediately gives A records)
- Any Cloud Run service -> ccc.com (Immediately gives A records)

However, the following does *not* work:

- Any Cloud Run service -> aaa.com (Spinner of death; never returned any DNS records after 12 hours)

Is there any where I can get more information on why this mapping is failing? The CLI also gives me a spinner when I run: `gcloud beta run domain-mappings create --service $SERVICE_NAME --domain aaa.com`

All domains were purchased through Google Domains . The only difference I can think of between aaa.com and bbb.com is that aaa.com was at some point using Cloudflare DNS, though I have since moved back to Google DNS.

Comment: This soundsmore like  bug than a question, would you mind contacting support or opening an issue at https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers and sharing as much details as you can (exact domain and project ID)?

Comment: Will do. Sorry, I didn't know where the appropriate place was to report bugs.

Comment: Hi, I' ve seen that you posted a  [issue-tracker issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/153767647) and found a workaround. Could you add this here for others to see?  https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1):

This problem magically resolved itself after a few days. Possibly what fixed it was switching my DNS from Cloudflare back to Google DNS and waiting for that to trickle through.

If you're experiencing this issue, one workaround is to just use `www.aaa.com` as your canonical name instead of `aaa.com`. You can use a CNAME record to map `www.aaa.com` to your Cloud Run service. Many DNS providers (including Google DNS) will give you the ability to create a 301 Redirect from `aaa.com` to `www.aaa.com`.